# Vue JS v-model data doesn't update when used with watch

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Here is my code

```js
data() {
  return {
    crop_mode: 'portrait',
    widget_data:''
  }
},

watch: {
  widget_data: function (val) {
    this.crop_mode = val.crop_mode
  },
},
```

This code is inside a modal component. So whenever a modal is opened, "widget_data" changes. And this widget_data has a "crop_mode" which needs to assigned to the data variable "crop_mode"

This works fine if I console.log the val.crop_mode but when I do v-model on crop_mode like below, it doesn't update the checked radio button.

```html
<label class="custom-radio block">
  <input
    type="radio"
    value="portrait"
    name="crop_mode"
    v-model="crop_mode"
  />
  <span>Portrait</span>
</label>
<label class="custom-radio block">
  <input
    type="radio"
    value="landscape"
    name="crop_mode"
    v-model="crop_mode"
  />
  <span>Landscape</span>
</label>
<label class="custom-radio block">
  <input
    type="radio"
    value="square"
    name="crop_mode"
    v-model="crop_mode"
  />
  <span>Square</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `deep:true` option because It looks like `widget_data` is an object with nested values:

```
watch: {
  widget_data:{
      handler(val) {
         this.crop_mode = val.crop_mode
      },
     deep:true
    }
},
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. Infact it broke other widgets too which has different data but they had crop_mode working fine.

Comment: try out init the data like `widget_data:{crop_mode:''}` instead `widget_data:''`

Comment: It's actually props of the component :P

Comment: It seems like the widget_data is conflicting with widget_data of another component. Let's say I have widget_data on watch in one component and also in another different component, will they conflict?